# Does 'Full width at half maximum' include ~76% of values or about 97.5%? Within its area?

Tags: definition, mathematics, error-analysis, statistics

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum):

> If the considered function is the density of a normal distribution of the form
>
> $${\displaystyle f(x)={\frac {1}{\sigma {\sqrt {2\pi }}}}\exp \left[-{\frac {(x-x_{0})^{2}}{2\sigma ^{2}}}\right]}$$
>
> where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation and x0 is the expected value, then the relationship between FWHM and the standard deviation is
> $${\displaystyle \mathrm {FWHM} =2{\sqrt {2\ln 2}}\;\sigma \approx 2.355\;\sigma .}$$
>
> The corresponding area within this FWHM accounts to approximately 76%.

A sigma of about 2.355 contains  approximately 97.5% of all values, correct?

I mean, two sigma is about ninety-five percent.

So how can the article then say only about 76% of values are within the FWHM?

I am very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kyle is right and here is some more detail.

If the full width is $2.355\sigma$, half of that is $1.1775\sigma$

From this table

[https://www.math.arizona.edu/~rsims/ma464/standardnormaltable.pdf](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Ersims/ma464/standardnormaltable.pdf)

that value gives $0.88$ to the left and about $0.12$ the the right, two lots of the $0.12$ are $0.24$, so 24% outside and 76% within the $\pm 1.1775\sigma$

Answer (score 10):

The key is that it's *full width* at half maximum, whereas you're thinking of $\pm 2.355\sigma$, which would have a total width of $4.710\sigma$.